# How to hide my personal information when I register a domain name?

Tags: dns, registration, domain-name

I registered several domain names (.de, .com) but even if I order the option to hide my whois record, it seems, there is always a way to retrieve my personal informations anyway (don't want everybody to be able to see where I live etc.).

There is surely a point I missed, or misunderstood.

Could someone clarify this to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There needs to be valid contact information in the whois database for a .com domain.

Some hosting providers offer privacy packets to hide your information.

I’m not sure if you can do the same with a .de domain name

Answer (score 0):

You may enable or disable the privacy protect during your [domain registration](http://hioxindia.com/checkAvailability.php) process.
But, the Privacy Protect option is not available for the following domain names: CA, .CO.NZ, .NET.NZ, .ORG.NZ, .TEL, .DE, .EU, .ES, .CO.IN, .NET.IN, .ORG.IN, .GEN.IN, .FIRM.IN, .IND.IN, .CO.UK, .ME.UK, .ORG.UK, .IN, .US, .ASIA.